# How to make update_attributes fail for mass assignment warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I constructed an object based on parameters and passed it into the update_attributes method, within my controller's update method.  The object had one attribute (xyz) that was not listed as part of attr_accessible list in the model. Rails skipped updating the attribute in question and generated a warning that mass-assignment of attribute xyz failed.

I would like to make sure that update_attributes fails if this kind of situation occurs instead of just getting a warning.  Is there a config setting or an option that can be passed in to the update_attributes call to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the config to use a sanitizer that will raise an exception:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

Edit: This is available since 3.2. Your question is tagged with rails 3.1, so it won't work. You can upgrade to 3.2, or take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558584/throw-an-exception-whenever-someone-tries-to-mass-assign-protected-attributes) on how to patch the sanitizer.

Comment: thanks a lot for the precise answer, and for providing options for both versions of rails!

Comment: If you are planning to upgrade to 3.2, I would recommend this railscast (which by the way mentions the change in the config): http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

Comment: Thanks aromero.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Set your own mass_assignment_sanitizer using [mass_assignment_sanitizer=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) and you probably want to look at active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb for examples and active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb for how to set up your own Sanitizer that will fail.